# java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Unknown Source) null request.getParameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, hql

I have  a hibernate app with servlet.
It is looking like I can not get an `Int` from a request or add it in to the session.
But how? I want to use it in in my HQL code. 
I just made dirty solution by replacing all `Integer` to `String` but HQL can't react on that.

I want to compare Integers.

1. Get price from jsp **number** input type (I use number input)
2. servlet would make variables by requesting them (fine works with String)
3. use variables as input to Java function
4. pass them as HQL arguments (works with String but I can`t compare String vars)

I need integer.

I have goods.prod

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>           java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>           java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       error.

```
public class prod implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue 
@Column(name = "id")

private String id;
private String catid;
private String name;
private Integer price;

public prod() {
}

public prod(String id, String catid, String name, Integer price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.catid = catid;
    this.name = name ;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getid() {
    return id;
}

 public void setid(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getcatid() {
    return catid;
}
public void setcatid(String catid) {
    this.catid = catid;
}

public String getname() {
    return name;
}    
public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getprice() {
    return price;
}   
public void setprice(Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

servlet.Indexservlet

```
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8670416133536111566L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     String catid = request.getParameter("catid");
     String id = request.getParameter("id");
     String name = request.getParameter("name");
     Integer pricel = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pricel"));
     Integer priceh = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("priceh"));


     prod dot = IndexService.getprodbyparam(catid,name,pricel,priceh);
     request.getSession().setAttribute("prod", dot);        
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

}

}
```

IndexService

```
import HibernateUtil.HibernateUtil;
import goods.prod;
public class IndexService {     
      public static prod getprodbyparam(String catid,String name,Integer pricel, Integer priceh) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;
            prod prod = null;
            try {
                tx = session.getTransaction();
                tx.begin();
                Query query = session.createQuery("from prod where name=? and price between ? and ?");

                query.setString(0, name);
                query.setInteger(1, pricel);
                query.setInteger(2, priceh);
                prod = (prod)query.uniqueResult();
                tx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return prod;
        }
}
```

Index.jsp part

```
<tr>
<td>Price h</td>
<td><input type="number" name="priceh" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
 <%
     prod prod = (prod) session.getAttribute("prod");
 %>     
 <b>You have<% if (null == prod) out.println("No text entered.");%></b>     
 <br/>
 <b>selected</b>    
  <br/>
  <%if (null!=prod) out.println(prod.getid()+ " "+prod.getname()+ " "+prod.getprice());%></b>   
 <br/>
```

Error was

```
type Exception report

message null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    servlet.IndexServlet.doPost(IndexServlet.java:29)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.33 logs.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of exception?

Comment: post your full stack

Answer (score 0):

Try casting this :

```
Integer pricel = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("pricel"));
```

Comment: Yes, it works and I use it. Problem was in wrong name. It was different in .jsp and other files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question by making it use the wrong input in jsp as price and nothing in my code checked that. I used `pricel` and `priceh` names in right code but in wrong names were another. The name used in JSP or html must correspond to each other.